# events.js:167 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event at ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing a simple mobile application using the ionic framework. And got this error on my **CLI** during the serve command `ionic serve`
Below I have mentioned the versions of my application

```
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.4.0 (C:\Users\Jahir\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0



Cordova:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms     : not available
Cordova Plugins       : not available


System:
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Jahir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v11.2.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.4.1
 OS                : Windows 7
```

I also posted my error elaborately from the CLI, please find it below

```
events.js:167
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
  at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
  at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)

Emitted 'error' event at:
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:252:12)
  at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
  at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
```

Please give me the solution, I know it is a simple error, a solution will be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just add it to the PATH: C:\Windows\System32 and start cmd as Administrator

Goto > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system setting\Enviroment variable and set system variables path C:\Windows\System32\ variable and restart your System.

Positively Hope, it will work

Comment: This procedure solve the issue? In my case no... Another idea? thans